# Backslide of Limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, backslide

**Backslide introduced in 9.0, and persisting through 12.0.**

---

A friend of mine showed me this example:

```
Limit[Sum[Sin[Pi*k/n]/(n + 1/k), {k, 1, n}], n -> Infinity]
```

This sample calculates well in *v8.0.4*:

> [image]

but not in v9.0.1 and v10.0 (tested on Cloud):

> [image]
>
> [image]

So this seems to be a backslide.

Any work-around?

---

**Addendum**

There's no doubt that the answer for the infinite summation is $2/\pi$, this can be proved by [squeeze theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem):

$$\because 0\leq1/k\leq1$$
$$\therefore \lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{n}\right)}{n+1}\right)\leq\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{k}+n}\right)\leq\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{n}\right)}{n}\right)$$
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{n \sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{n}\right)}{n}}{n+1}\leq\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{k}+n}\right)\leq\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{n}\right)}{n}\right)$$
$$\because\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{n}\right)}{n}\right)=\int_0^1 \sin (\pi  x) \, dx=\frac{2}{\pi }$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{n}{n+1}=1$$
$$\therefore\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  k}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{k}+n}\right)=\frac{2}{\pi }$$

Comment: I have yet to verify this, but: Is $2/\pi$ actually the correct solution?

Comment: @Jinxed `ListLogPlot[
 Table[2/Pi - N@Sum[Sin[Pi*k/n]/(n + 1/k), {k, 1, n}], {n, 1000}]]` suggests that it might be.

Comment: @Jinxed The sum is a Riemann Sum for `Integrate[Sin[Pi x], {x, 0, 1}]`, which equals `2/Pi`.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thx, I missed that.

Comment: @MichaelE2: But is it really a Riemann sum? Isn't there a mismatch between the interval parameter for `Sin` and the interval widths `1/(n+1/k)`?

Comment: @Jinxed I was going to say that the form it is in does not look like a Riemann sum and requires some (considerable) manipulation.  From the summand `n^2 xk Sin[Pi xk]/ (1 + n^2 xk) * (1/n)` where `xk = k/n`, one can argue that it is equal to `Sin[Pi ck] * (1/n)`, for an appropriate `ck` for `xk < 0.5` and for a `ck` from the next interval up for `xk > 0.5`, which does not affect the limit as `n -> Infinity`.  The argument is subtler than a comment allows.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Jinxed I suppose one could also think of it as a Riemann sum from `x = 1/n` to `x = 1/n + Sum[1/(n+1/k), {k, 1, n}]` with your interval width `1/(n + 1/k)` and argue that in the limit it approaches the integral from 0 to 1.  That's probably simpler.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I added a step-by-step proof, have a look.

Comment: @xzczd Yes, that's quite nice, but I did not doubt the result.  Note that the LHS is also a Riemann sum for the same integral if you sum $k=0$ to $n$ with $n+1$ intervals.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yeah, I know, I just feel obligated to remind all the people who take part in the discussion for the correctness of v8 :)

Comment: By `Laplace Transform`: `InverseLaplaceTransform[
  Limit[Sum[
     LaplaceTransform[Exp[I a*Pi*k/n]/(n + 1/k), a, s], {k, 1, n}] // 
    FullSimplify, n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> s > 0], s, 1] // Im`

Comment: Another workaround is to find the series at infinity. `In[60]:= Series[
   Sum[Sin[Pi*k/n]/(n + 1/k), {k, 1, n}], {n, \[Infinity], 0}] // 
  Normal // Expand

Out[60]= 2/\[Pi]`

Answer (score 6):

One possible workaround is to use the new in M12 function [`AsymptoticSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AsymptoticSum):

```
AsymptoticSum[Sin[Pi k/n]/(n + 1/k), {k, 1, n}, {n, ∞, 1}]
```

> 2/

Answer (score 4):

Yesterday I found the approach below with `Hold`/`ReleaseHold` on **v10.0.0** on Win8.1 achieves the same result as **v8.0.4**, namely, it gives a limit of $\frac{2}{\pi}$.

```
ReleaseHold@Limit[
    Hold[
        Sum[Sin[Pi*k/n]/(n + 1/k), {k, 1, n}]
    ], n -> Infinity]
(* 2/Pi *)
```

However, on **v10.0.2** on Linux, this approach gives the result shown below...[as does Wolfram Alpha](http://bit.ly/19L08Mr). Also in a comment by Jinxed below, apparently this is the result in **v10.1**! Can anyone confirm the result on other operating systems or versions?

```
$Version
(* 10.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014) *)

Limit[Sum[Sin[Pi*k/n]/(n + 1/k), {k, 1, n}], n -> Infinity]
```

[image]

---

**Addendum**

Numerically, one can try this to investigate the behaviour of the function as `n` increases, and it looks like $\frac{2}{\pi}$ is along the right lines.

```
func = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
            2/Pi - Sum[Sin[Pi*k/n]/(n + 1/k), {k, 1, n}]
       ];
data = Table[func[n], {n, 10000}];
ListLogPlot[data, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"n", "func[n]"}]
```

[image]

On top of that, you can convert the `LerchPhi` mess into a function and plot the behaviour of that (include `Chop` to remove some small imaginary components). It's the same behaviour as the original sum:

```
func2[n_] := 2/Pi - Chop@N@(-((1/(2*(-1 + E^((I*Pi)/n))*n^2))*((I*((-E^((I*Pi)/n))*n - E^((2*I*Pi)/n)*n + (E^(-((I*Pi)/n)))^(-1 + n)*n + E^((2*I*Pi)/n)*(E^((I*Pi)/n))^n*n - LerchPhi[E^(-((I*Pi)/n)), 1, 1 + 1/n] +  E^((I*Pi)/n)*  LerchPhi[E^(-((I*Pi)/n)), 1,    1 + 1/n] - (E^(-((I*Pi)/n)))^(-1 + n)*  LerchPhi[E^(-((I*Pi)/n)), 1,    1 + 1/n + n] + (E^(-((I*Pi)/n)))^n*  LerchPhi[E^(-((I*Pi)/n)), 1, 1 + 1/n + n] +  E^((2*I*Pi)/n)*LerchPhi[E^((I*Pi)/n), 1, 1 + 1/n] - E^((3*I*Pi)/n)*LerchPhi[E^((I*Pi)/n), 1, 1 + 1/n] -  E^((2*I*Pi)/n)*(E^((I*Pi)/n))^n*LerchPhi[E^((I*Pi)/n), 1, 1 + 1/n + n] + E^((3*I*Pi)/n)*(E^((I*Pi)/n))^n*LerchPhi[E^((I*Pi)/n), 1, 1 + 1/n + n]))/E^((I*Pi)/n))))?Q

data2 = ParallelTable[func2[n], {n, 1, 1000, 5}];
ListLogPlot[Transpose[{Range[1, 1000, 5], data2}], 
      Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"n", "func2[n]"}]
```

[image]

Comment: My guess is that version 8 can't symbolically evaluate the `Sum`, which would have the same effect as using `Hold`/`ReleaseHold` in 9 and 10.

Comment: @2012rcampion Interesting idea!

Comment: @xzczd, can you try evaluating the sum by itself in v8?

Comment: @blochwave, @xzczd: The `Hold`-`ReleaseHold`-approach does **not** work in 10.1!

Comment: @Jinxed Oh! What does it give, out of interest?

Comment: @blochwave: Something you already know ;) : `Limit[-(1/(2 (-1 + E^((I \[Pi])/n)) n^2))
  I E^(-((I \[Pi])/
    n)) (-E^(((I \[Pi])/n)) n - 
     E^((2 I \[Pi])/n) n + (E^(-((I \[Pi])/n)))^(-1 + n) n + 
     E^((2 I \[Pi])/n) (E^((I \[Pi])/n))^n n - 
     LerchPhi[E^(-((I \[Pi])/n)), 1, 1 + 1/n] + 
     E^((I \[Pi])/n)
       LerchPhi[E^(-((I \[Pi])/n)), 1, 
       1 + 1/n] - (E^(-((I \[Pi])/n)))^(-1 + n)
       LerchPhi[E^(-((I \[Pi])/n)), 1, 
       1 + 1/n + n] + (E^(-((I \[Pi])/n)))^
      n LerchPhi[E^(-((I \[Pi])/n)), 1, 1 + 1/n + n] + ` and more coming.

Comment: Oh dear...that's not very neat!

Comment: @blochwave: Exactly the same, as if `Hold` had _not_ been applied.

Comment: @2012rcampion V8 can handle the finite summation: http://i.stack.imgur.com/urNrR.png

Comment: @xzczd Really... now this is getting interesting!

Comment: BTW the `Hold`-`ReleaseHold` approach also works in v8.0.4, I feel it really surprising: In this case `Limit[Hold[Sum[Sin[Pi*k/n]/(n + 1/k), {k, 1, n}]], n -> Infinity]` returns `Hold[2/π]` i.e. `Hold` doesn't hold the expression! Quite unusual!

Comment: It's just got weirder...

Comment: `?Q` should be deleted from `func2[n_]`. @dr.blochwave

Answer (score 4):

### Update

Since you gave a good proof, that $2/\pi$ is the correct solution, *Mathematica* is obviously failing at the task. The question is, why.

### Analysis of *Mathematica*'s behavior

First, the sum you gave is no Riemann sum:

You defined the intervals as
$$\Delta x_k=\frac{1}{n+1/k}$$
so $k/n$ does *not* lie within the appropriate subinterval, e.g. for $n=10$, $k/n=\frac{1}{10}$ (with $k=1$), while the interval width $1/(n+1/k)=\frac{1}{11}$ is less, observe:

```
NumberLinePlot@{Flatten@{FoldList[Plus, 0, 
 Table[(10 + 1/k)^-1, {k, 1, 10}]], 1}, Table[k/10, {k, 1, 10}]}
```

[image: intervals vs. parameters to Sin]

So, this is no Riemann sum. *Mathematica* deals with Rieman sums easily:

**General Riemann-sum**

Riemann sum for $[a,b]$:

```
riemann[f_,a_,b_,n_]:=With[{dx=(b-a)/n}, dx Sum[f[k dx], {k, 1, n}]]

Limit[riemann[Sin[\[Pi] #]&, 0, 1, n], n->Infinity]
(* 2/\[Pi] *)
```

### Mathematica's behavior

We have *no* Riemann sum here. *Mathematica* now seems to resort to LerchPhi and exponentialization, as soon as $k$ and $n$ appear together in the sum's divisor, possibly due to the Lerch zeta-function being defined as:

$$L(\lambda ,n ,s)=\sum _{{k=0}}^{\infty }{\frac {\exp(2\,\pi \,i\,\lambda \,k)}{(k+n)^{s}}}$$

Now, *Mathematica* seems to find enough resemblance in this to begin transforming the original summand into a Lerch-based form, ending up with the complex expression in the question, for which it then cannot find a limit anymore.

### Conclusion: Solution?

Having tried a number of documented summation methods in `Sum`, none of them prevent the expansion to Lerch. Since @blochwave's `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` does not work in 10.1 anymore, I am at a loss on how to actually have *Mathematica* find the limit of $2/\pi$.

The solution would be to prevent *Mathematica* from trying `LerchPhi` at all - how this might be accomplished is however beyond me. :|

Comment: +1 interesting work - I like it! The behaviour of the different versions of MMA w.r.t `Hold`/`ReleaseHold` is odd though - esp. on different OSs

Comment: @blochwave: Thanks! And this also raises the question, if previous *Mathematica*'s actually returned a _wrong_ result by giving `2/π`...

Comment: Yes, that's a very good point.

Comment: Aren't all the answers returned by the different *Mathematica* versions in fact equal?  I can't check now, but I thought that's what I got.

Comment: @MichaelE2: I fail to see, how $2/π$ matches up with the long result the OP (and myself) got for his original question.

Comment: @Jinxed numerically the `LerchPhi` thing does seem to tend to $2/\pi$ as $n$ increases.

Comment: @blochwave: What I wanted to say was: I am unable to manually evaluate the (long, LerchPhi) result myself. I just think, that the OP's original query does not immediately lend itself as being similar (or even equal) to the Riemann sum.

Comment: I'm sorry but the answer given by v8 is undoubtedly correct. See my edit for the step-by step proof. @blochwave

Comment: @xzczd: Nicely done! +1

Comment: @xzczd, @blochwave: I think I might have found a reason for `LerchPhi` showing up at all (see my update). Alas, now it seems utterly impossible to have *Mathematica* come up with the right result _at all_.