# Nesting BaseForm several functions deep causes dependent functions to not fully evaluate. Solutions?

Tags: system-limitations

Below is a simplified scenario of a problem that I'm running into. There are 3 functions each wrapped with `BaseForm[]` and a default base of 10 is passed to each through the optional `f` parameter. Each function depends on the function before it.

```
Add[a_, b_, f_:10] := BaseForm[a + b, f]
MultSum[a_, b_, c_, f_:10] := BaseForm[Add[a, b]*c, f]
ExpMultSum[a_, b_, c_, d_, f_:10] := BaseForm[MultSum[a, b, c]^d, f]
```

Please be aware the functions above have nothing to do with what I'm trying to accomplish. They only exist to highlight the issue that I am encountering.

I intentionally avoid passing in the `f` to the earlier functions because the output format isn't parseable by the caller. `Add[]` works fine, as does `MultSum[]`, but once we get to `ExpMultSum[]` the *Mathematica 9* parser appears to hit some internal limitation and stops evaluating the expression:

```
Add[2, 2]
4

MultSum[2,2,2]
8

ExpMultSum[2, 2, 2, 2]
8²
```

My best guess is that there is a nesting limitation? The only solution I can come up with is to move the BaseForm outside the function and wrap each call (ex. `BaseForm[Add[2, 2],10]`). Is there a known workaround so I can keep the BaseForm internal to the function?

Comment: `BaseForm[]` is only intended for output formatting. Why not do your arithmetic conventionally, and reserve `BaseForm[]` when you're ready to display output?

Comment: That's how I was originally doing it, but to save myself from having to constantly type `BaseForm[expression,n]` it was convenient to add it to the function itself.

Comment: And that worked out well for you, eh? You can set up `$PrePrint` to have your output be always printed in base $k$ form, for some globally set value of `k`.

Comment: It works for two levels of depth. =P The base changes quite a bit. So sadly $PrePrint wouldn't do the trick, but it's good to know the option exists.

Comment: You change the globally set value of the base as appropriate. Unless there's something you're not telling, you shouldn't need to perform any conversions if you're just doing arithmetic.

Comment: Wouldn't that create a scoping problem? Either we leave $PrePrint always set or it has to be unset before the return value. `Add[a_, b_, f_: 10] := 
 Module[{}, $PrePrint = BaseForm[#1, f] &; 
  Return[a + b]; $PrePrint =.]` But that isn't possible before the return unless there is a mechanism to defer execution or to always execute cleanup code following a module call.

Comment: Somehow I feel there's something you're missing. Are you aware that all arithmetic is done internally in binary anyway, and you thus don't need to set the base up until you need to display your result in the front end?

Comment: Imagine we want to run `Add[]` and sometimes view it in Base-2. Then in other scenarios we want to use it normally in Base-10. `Add[]` is a primitive for more complicated operations where presentation isn't necessary. So there is no need to pass in a BaseForm value. `Add[]` gets used in `MultSum[]`, which we occasionally want to view in a different base, and `MultSum[]` gets used in `ExpMultSum[]` which we also would like to sometimes view in something other than base-10. Putting the BaseForm[] in the function is purely a macro to save keystrokes and for readability of long expressions.

Comment: Why should your two more complicated functions have to take input in a different base? A number's a number, regardless of representation.

Comment: I think I see the confusion. They don't. `MultSum[a_, b_, c_, f_:10] := BaseForm[Add[a, b]*c, f]`. Notice the "base" of MultSum's `f` isn't passed in to `Add[]`. `Add[]` uses the default value of `f:10` as defined in the function declaration `Add[a_, b_, f_:10]`.

Comment: (1) This is not the result of any internal limitation. It is a consequence of applying operations intended for arithmetic expressions instead to expressions of the form `BaseForm[...]`. If you do `FullForm[...]` of the outputs this will become more clear.

Comment: (2) In essence this is an oft-duplicated question, though usually in regards to results wrapped in `MatrixForm[]`. As in "Why doesn't `mat={{1,2},{3,4}}//MatrixForm;RowReduce[mat]` work?". Same issue.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Is there a reason `BaseForm[expression,10]` should be treated differently than any other output, other than that it is being processed through a formatting function? It would be handy if there was a way to selectively disable the outer BaseForm wrapper when using the default case (perhaps through a property?).

Comment: I don't know why `BaseForm[expr,10]` formats without the "sub_10" part in contrast to other bases. But that's in the formatting handler. The fact is `XXXForm` wrappers do not go away, so functions that see them in input need to be prepared for handling them.

Comment: If the formatting handler recognizes that it's using the default case, it seems there should also be a way to simply treat the `XXXForm` as a pass through. Thank you for your insight Daniel.

Comment: How an expression is formatted does not in any way affect the expression. In particular, the expression `BaseForm[number,10]` does not become transformed to `number`. It might be an oversimplification, but it would be useful to regard evaluation and formatting as separate things. Maybe regard formatting as a side effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a customized `BaseForm`:

```
(* Solution 1 *)    
baseForm[num_, n_] := BaseForm[num //. BaseForm[a_, _] :> a, n]
(* Solution 2, may be dangerous *)
baseForm[num_, n_] := BaseForm[Block[{BaseForm = # &}, num], n]
```

But personally I think keeping `BaseForm` out of the function definition is better. If you feel it cumbersome to type `BaseForm` from time to time, just define a shorter name for it:

```
b[n_] := BaseForm[#, n] &
5 // b@4
```

[image]

---

**Update:**

The following solution should handle `Add[1, 2] + Add[3, 4]`:

```
(* Solution 3 *)
Clear@baseForm

baseForm /: (c : Except[SetDelayed | baseForm])[d___, baseForm[a_, b_], e___] := 
  baseForm[c[d, a, e], b]
baseForm /: MakeBoxes[baseForm[a_, b_], fmt_] := ToBoxes@BaseForm[a, b]
```

---

**Update 2:**

```
(* Solution 4 *)
baseForm[num_, n_] := ($PrePrint = BaseForm[#, n] &; num)
```

This solution should be the most robust and sufficient for so long.

Comment: Clever, I like it! Both solutions solve the nesting problem, but performing an operation like: `Add[1,2]+Add[3,4]` results in `3+7` instead of `10` due to the default value `f_:10` in `Add[a_, b_, f_:10]`. So close!

Comment: @DustinDarcy See my edit.

Comment: That's one crazy transform! It works, but when the situation gets a bit more hairy (ex. `Sum[x, {x, 0, Add[1, 2]}]`) it generates: `Sum::vloc: "The variable {x,0,3} cannot be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values."` I think it's best to write this one off as being more trouble than it's worth. Your answer definitely wins though and is probably as close as we're going to get without a rewrite of how `BaseForm[]` treats the default case. Thank you for all your effort.

Comment: @DustinDarcy Thanks for accepting. As to the new sample, it seems that `baseForm` failed to escape from `Sum`. This may be because `Sum` has used some unusual rule for summation. ([Here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64633/backslide-of-limit#comment213699_78777) is an evidence for the unusualness of `Sum`.) A quick fix I can think out is to define a customized `Sum`:  `sum[f_, {x_, a_, b_}] := Sum[f, {x, #, #2}] &[a, b]`. This is probably not the only edge case though 囧.

Comment: @DustinDarcy Have a look at my **update 2**, this solution should be quite robust. The only trouble is that `$PrePrint` won't be automatically cleared but it's not a big deal. When you don't want to see the `BaseForm` of the output anymore, just `$PrePrint=.`

Comment: After J.M's recommendation I created [something a bit similar using the $PrePrint hack](http://goo.gl/DVs4xn), but there is no way automatically unset `$PrePrint` before the return. As mentioned earlier the notebook has a large number of calls to `BaseForm[]`. So having to manually unset $PrePrint would almost be as cumbersome as constantly writing out: `BaseForm[expression, X]`. Thanks for keeping at it though, xzczd!

Comment: @DustinDarcy Maybe I haven't understand the situation correctly, but are you awaring that `$PrePrint` doesn't need to be unset before being set to a new function? : http://i.stack.imgur.com/5YaFr.png

Comment: Yep. The notebook I'm working with looks more like this: `BaseForm[expression,2]; expression; BaseForm[expression,8]; expression;` So after each BaseForm expression I'd have to clear `$PrePrint` to return the output back to the normal base-10; or every normal line in the notebook that doesn't use `BaseForm[]` would have to be converted to use the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

One solution that works when the value isn't being stored if it's not base-10 is to use a wrapper to conditionally apply the BaseForm.

`baseForm[e_,n_]:=If[n==10,e,BaseForm[e,n]]`

This fixes the nesting problem because `BaseForm[]` is only applied in the last call of the execution stack. It is too bad `BaseForm[]` doesn't do this by default.

Comment: Oh… so there doesn't exist something like `a = Add[2, 2, 3](* line break *)
a + a` in your notebook?

Comment: Good observation, most of the `BaseForm[expression, _not_ 10]` operations output unstored values which are later referenced by the line number or the result rather than variable to point out changes that are happening. That is definitely a limitation of this approach. Time to go back through the notebook to double check what it might have messed up.