# Strange behavior of UpSetDelayed together with MakeBoxes

Tags: core-language, boxes, upvalues

In order to answer [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100498/1871), I just stumbled into the world of `UpValues`. Though I managed to find a solution for the problem, I'm confused by my own code now 囧, consider the following line of code:

```
baseForm /: MakeBoxes[baseForm[a_, b_], fmt_] := ToBoxes@BaseForm[a, b]
```

It makes `baseForm` display like `BaseForm`, by setting upvalue to… where?

"That goes without saying, it's in `baseForm`!" Huh?:

```
UpValues /@ {baseForm, TagSetDelayed, MakeBoxes, a, b, 
             Pattern, fmt, SetDelayed, ToBoxes, BaseForm}
(* {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}} *)
```

The upvalue(?) can be found in the `Information` of `baseForm`, indeed:

```
??baseForm
```

[image]

But where is it stored in?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assignments to `MakeBoxes` and `Format` get special treatment.  The definitions are stored as (under-documented) [FormatValues](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules.html#6025):

```
FormatValues[baseForm] // InputForm

(* 
{HoldPattern[MakeBoxes[baseForm[a_, b_], fmt_]] :> ToBoxes[BaseForm[a, b]]}
*)
```

Note that if we omit `InputForm` from the expression above, then the system will attempt to apply the formatting to `baseForm` within the definition itself and give a misleading result:

```
FormatValues[baseForm]

(*
BaseForm::intpm: Positive machine-sized integer expected at position 2 in BaseForm[a_,b_]. >>

BaseForm::intpm: Positive machine-sized integer expected at position 2 in BaseForm[a,b]. >>

{HoldPattern[MakeBoxes[BaseForm[a_,b_],fmt_]]:>ToBoxes[BaseForm[a,b]]}
*)
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that `FormatValues` existed! "Under-documented" even feels a bit euphemistic though...

Comment: Gee, I stumbled over this problem now for the second time. Good to have StackExchange. I wish I could upvote for a second time. Many thanks to WReach!