# Modify StandardForm of E

Tags: front-end, notebooks, customization, conversion, boxes

`StandardForm` of `E` is `\[ExponentialE]`, can we modify it to something else?

I thought I could use `MakeBoxes` and `InterpretationBox` like the following:

```
MakeBoxes[E, StandardForm] := 
 InterpretationBox[StyleBox[ "ℰ", FontColor -> #], E] &@Orange
```

[image]

But as we can see, it doesn't work as expected. The method does work for simpler case, though:

```
MakeBoxes[a, StandardForm] := 
 InterpretationBox[StyleBox[ "α", FontColor -> #], a] &@Orange
```

[image]

What's wrong with my attempt? What's the correct way to modify `StandardForm` of `E`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply due to definition priority mechanism.

Each of these three works:

```
GeneralUtilities`BlockProtected[E,
  E /: MakeBoxes[E, StandardForm] := 
    InterpretationBox[StyleBox["ℰ", FontColor -> #], E] &@Orange;
]
E
```

```
GeneralUtilities`BlockProtected[E,
  E/:MakeBoxes[E, _]=.;
];
MakeBoxes[E, StandardForm] := 
  InterpretationBox[StyleBox["ℰ", FontColor -> #], E] &@Orange
E
```

```
GeneralUtilities`BlockProtected[E,
  Format[E, StandardForm] := 
    Interpretation[Style[ "ℰ", FontColor -> Orange], E]
]
E
```

We can see that a `Format` definition precedes a `MakeBoxes` definition (this is documented), and the one bound to `E` precedes the one bound to `MakeBoxes`

---

To revert the changes:

```
GeneralUtilities`BlockProtected[E,
  MakeBoxes[E, StandardForm]=.;
  E/:MakeBoxes[E, StandardForm]=.;
  Format[E, StandardForm]=.;
  E/:MakeBoxes[E, _]:="\[ExponentialE]"
] //Quiet
```

Comment: Interesting, so there's a hidden upvalue for `E`. Then I'd like to point out that, the `Format` solution is inferior compared with the `MakeBox` solutions, just try converting the `E` with Ctrl+Shift+N, or editing the output, you'll know what I mean.

Comment: @xzczd 1. I think it's not hidden, which you can see it in `FormatValues@E`;

Comment: 2. That's true, that causes an infinite recursion.

Comment: Oh I forgot about `FormatValues`! But `FormatValues` is not documented, and usually the format value can be checked with `??` ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100518/1871)'s an example) but it's not the case for `E`, so I'd still argue this is hidden :) .

Comment: @xzczd Which is to blame is ```Internal`InformationDefinitions``` . As I use ```GeneralUtilities`PrintDefinitions``` more, it won't hide from me.