# Why this upvalue doesn't escape from Sum?

Tags: pattern-matching, summation, core-language, implementation-details, upvalues

Probably a hard question, but I decide to cry out loud :).

This is actually another problem I encountered when answering [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100498/1871). Consider the following transform rule stored as an upvalue:

```
(a : Except@If)[b___, f[c_, d_], e___] ^:= f[a[b, c, e], d]
```

*See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68823/what-does-f-whocalled-f-really-mean#comment273246_100686) to understand why I added the `Except@If`.*

It can not escape from the index of `Sum`:

```
Sum[x, {x, 1, f[3, a]}]
```

> Sum::vloc :  The variable  {x,1,3}  cannot be localized so that it can be assigned to numerical values
>
> ```
> Sum[x, {{x, 1, 3}}, a]
> ```

What's going on here?

I believe this is somewhat related to [this behavior of `Sum`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64633/backslide-of-limit#comment213699_78777) that no longer exists in v10, which is another unsolved mystery.

Comment: The `f` in the sum expression is inside a list and so it won't match your pattern.

Comment: What would you like `Sum[x, {x, 1, f[3, a]}]` to become?

Comment: @M.R. A list is just a expression with head `List`. My transformation rule should escape from any expression whose head isn't `If` but it fails on `Sum`. To see the expected behavior, just try something like `sum[x, {x, 1, f[3, a]}]`.

Comment: `Sum` has `HoldAll` attribute so in `Sum[x, {x, 1, f[3, a]}]` expression, `{x, 1, f[3, a]}` is not immediately evaluated, so `f`'s up value is not used before evaluation of "body" of `Sum` function starts. `{x, 1, f[3, a]}` is evaluated in some unknown place inside "body" of `Sum` function and that's where  `f`'s up value is used, leading to this strange behavior.

Comment: @jkuczm ……To be honest, I didn't notice the influence of `HoldAll`. (I thought upvalues can always escape from `Hold`!) You can elaborate this to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To experiment with [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues.html) let's define simple up-value on `f`, that gathers `g` and `h` heads, if `f` is used inside them.

```
ClearAll[f, g, h]
(head : g | h)[f[args___]] ^:= f[args, head]
```

We can use [`TracePrint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TracePrint.html) to visualize steps of [Standard Evaluation Sequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html) of `h[f[]]` expression.

```
h[f[]] // TracePrint
(* h[f[]]  Evaluation of h[f[]] expression starts.
    h      Head h evaluates to itself.
    f[]    Evaluation of f[], i.e. first argument of h[f[]], starts.
     f     Head f evaluates to itself,
           f[] has no arguments and no matching DownValues,
           so evaluation of f[] finishes, it evaluates to itself.
           Evaluation of arguments of h[f[]] expression finishes.
           UpValues associated with arguments of h[f[]] expression are used.
   f[h]    f's upvalue replaces h[f[]] with f[h].
           f[h] expression evaluation starts.
    f      Head f evaluates to itself.
    h      First argument h evaluates to itself. *)
(* Out[]= f[h] *)
```

If we nest `f` deeper in `h`:

```
h[g[f[]]] // TracePrint
 (* h[g[f[]]]
     h
     g[f[]]
      g
      f[]
       f
     f[g]      f's UpValues are used while evaluating g[f[]] expression.
      f
      g
    h[f[g]]    As a result of evaluation of g[f[]] argument we get f[g].
    f[g, h]    f's UpValues ere used while evaluating h[f[g]] expression.
     f
     g
     h *)
(* Out[]= f[g, h] *)
```

We see that `UpValues` are used only when they are associated with expression at first level of currently evaluated expression.

Now let's see what changes when we add [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) attribute to `h`.

```
ClearAll[h]
SetAttributes[h, HoldAll]

h[f[]] // TracePrint
(* h[f[]]
    h
   f[h]
    f
    h *)
(* Out[]= f[h] *)
```

We see that arguments of `h` are not evaluated, but `UpValues` of `f` are still used.

But what happens if `f` is deeper than at first level of `h`:

```
h[g[f[]]] // TracePrint
(* h[g[f[]]]
    h *)
(* Out[]= h[g[f[]]] *)
```

Since `g[f[]]` argument of `h` is not evaluated, `f`'s `UpValues` are not used at all. Analogous thing happens in expression from question.

For completeness let's also check what happens when [`HoldAllComplete`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAllComplete.html) attribute is used.

```
ClearAll[h]
SetAttributes[h, HoldAllComplete]

h[f[]] // TracePrint
(* h[f[]]
    h *)
(* Out[]= h[f[]] *)
```

Now `UpValues` are not used even if `f[]` expression is at first level of `h`.

---

Going back to expression from question.

[`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) has `HoldAll` attribute, so although this does not prevent usage of `UpValues` of expressions that are at first level in `Sum`, it does prevent evaluation of those expressions.

In `Sum[x, {x, 1, f[3, a]}]` expression, `UpValues` of `x` (first argument) and `List` (head of second argument) are tested, but since `{x, 1, f[3, a]}` expression is not evaluated (due to `HoldAll` attribute of `Sum`), `UpValues` of `f` are not tested, so standard evaluation of `Sum` proceeds.

Arguments of `Sum` are passed to "body" of `Sum` function and evaluated somewhere there. So `UpValues` of `f` are used in some unknown code inside body of `Sum` and they break it, they may also interfere with error reporting of `Sum`.

This is one of examples showing that such catch-all `UpValues` can be dangerous, and can lead to unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might have to use holds to prevent the unwanted evaluation during the transformations:

[image]